# mysqldump to remote mysql database using gzip

Tags: linux, mysql, gzip

I'm trying to transfer data from one MySQL server to another with gzip compression. What I have so far is:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[pwd] --no-create-db --no-create-info [db] [table] | gzip -c | mysql -h [host] -u [user] -p[pwd]
```

Of course this doesn't work because the compressed data is being imported into to the remote DB. How do I go about uncompressing the data on the remote server before import - or will this not work and do I need to use SSH?

Thanks

Comment: I have this working through multiple commands with SSH, but I'd like to get working with one line command using pipes, if possible

Comment: Why do you have gzip in here at all?

Comment: To compress the data for transfer

Comment: I'd just go with `mysql --compress` myself.  It's already built into the client/server protocol.  Reference:  [MySQL command options - compress](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_compress)

Answer (score 2):

You can - via multiple SSH pipes.

For example:

```
ssh user@host1 "mysqldump -u [user] -p[pwd] --no-create-db --no-create-info [db] [table] | gzip -c" | ssh user@host2 "gzip -c -d | mysql -h [host] -u [user] -p[pwd]"
```

Breaking this down a bit, you have two SSH commands, piped to each other:

- The first one runs the `mysqldump`, then pipes the result to `gzip`, which in turns sends the result to STDOUT.
- The second command takes STDIN and decompresses it, then pipes it to the `mysql` command.

When you combine the two commands, you can pass data between two hosts directly using SSH.

Example in practice below:

```
cwatson@zeus:~$ ssh tyr

cwatson@tyr:~$ echo stuff123tyr > testfile.txt
cwatson@tyr:~$ cat testfile.txt
stuff123tyr
cwatson@tyr:~$ logout

ssh tyr "cat ~/testfile.txt | gzip -c" | ssh thor "gzip -c -d > ~/testfile.txt"

cwatson@zeus:~$ ssh thor
Last login: Fri Feb 26 17:28:01 2016 from host217-44-218-9.range217-44.btcentralplus.com
cwatson@thor:~$ cat testfile.txt
stuff123tyr
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Craig!

Comment: @user3571061 no problem. Also take note of funkyhat's answer too - SSH does natively compress data, but you may get better transfer times if you compress before the data hits SSH by using something like `pigz` which is multi-threaded `gzip`.

Answer (score 2):

By using the parameter `--compress`, MySQL client can send compressed data to the remote server. So, the transfer command line may be modified to:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[pwd] --compress --no-create-db --no-create-info [db] [table] | \
 mysql --compress -h [host] -u [user] -p[pwd]
```

Note that data will be sent unencrypted over the network. If it concerns you, piping the dump through SSH is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to use some kind of remote execution in order to get the remote side to do the decompression:

`mysqldump -u [user] -p[pwd] --no-create-db --no-create-info [db] [table] | gzip -c | ssh [host] "gunzip | mysql -h localhost -u [user] -p[pwd]"`

However bear in mind that ssh does compression transparently by default - the g(un)zip steps are unnecessary.

`mysqldump -u [user] -p[pwd] --no-create-db --no-create-info [db] [table] | ssh [host] mysql -h localhost -u [user] -p[pwd]`
should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Pre Requesite

- create sender  database if it does not exist
- create receiver database if it does not exist
- file will be saved in home directory if path not changed
- make sure u r using correct credentials
- To  get receiver user type this on commandline(ctrl+alt+t) ---> `whoami`
- To  get receiver ip address type this on commandline(ctrl+alt+t) ---> `ifconfig |grep "inet addr"|head -1`

`mysqldump -u{sender dbuser} -p{sender dbpassword} {sender database name} | gzip -cf | ssh {receiver user}@{receiver ip address} ' cat >/home/myfilename.gz | gzip -dc < myfilenamegz |mysql -u{receiver username} -p{receiver dbuser}  {receiver dbname}  '`

- remove `{ }` from command and insert your values